# Set "Fit Text Width" as default when opening Word Document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I'm partially sighted and as such have difficutly reading word documents unless I set the zoom level to "Fit Text Width". I've been doing this manually and was wondering how I set it as the default zoom level for all documents when I open themT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more complicated than it sounds, the reason being is that there is no one default zoom that is used when a document is opened, rather each document is opened at the zoom that was set the last time it was edited (even with documents coming from other machines).

The next best thing would be to have a quick way to change the zoom settings to "fit text" for any document loaded, however for some reason this command is missing from the customize keyboard option menu where you can normally assign a key combination to a particular command. Instead you could use the built-in keyboard commands to make your way to the menu, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> + Arrow over to the correct option or setup a custom macro to do this and bind it to a keyboard shortcut:

```
Sub SetFitTextZoom()
    ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.PageFit = wdPageFitTextFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks ever so much for that - no wonder I couldn't find the answer online anywhere - figured it would be just a setting somewhere! Very much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

Adding new module with this two macros to a document template (as described [here](http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/10926-change-default-zoom-size-page-width.html)) seems to work for me:

```
Sub AutoOpen()
    ActiveWindow.View.Type = 3
    ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.PageFit = wdPageFitBestFit
End Sub

Sub AutoNew()
    ActiveWindow.View.Type = 3
    ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.PageFit = wdPageFitBestFit
End Sub
```

You should [allow macros](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-or-disable-macros-in-Office-files-12b036fd-d140-4e74-b45e-16fed1a7e5c6).
Office 2010